# Tortoisesvn could not get subversion project

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have create Repository using Tortoise svn-1.8.0.244 then  after i have tried to add subversion on visual studio 2012 but i cant add subversion it is says "unable to connect a repository at URL file:///D:/Nop3.0_svn"

i have given to sharedect in MVC4 and operating system windows 7 and 64 bit then i have installed Tortoise svn version- 1.8.0.24401-x64- svn-1.8.0.

Comment: Can you check out the repo with TortoiseSVN from that location?

Comment: Is it even possible to connect to a SVN repository directly on the file system?